# Why != is not correct for this self joins query in psql

Tags: mysql, psql

The following is the code for creating the table

```
create table residences(
id integer
references students,
building text
references buildings(name),
room text
);
```

The following is the code for query.

```
select a.id, b.id, a.building, a.room
    from residences as a, residences as b
where a.building = b.building
and a.room = b.room
and a.id > b.id
order by a.building, a.room;


|     id |     id | building | room |
+--------+--------+----------+------+
| 881256 | 413001 |   Crosby |   10 |
| 741532 | 496747 |   Crosby |   19 |
| 931027 | 612413 |   Crosby |   31 |
| 958827 | 170267 | Dolliver |    1 |
| 707536 | 104131 | Dolliver |   14 |
| 505241 | 477801 | Dolliver |    8 |
| 824292 | 118199 | Kendrick |   1A |
| 231742 | 105540 | Kendrick |   3B |
+--------+--------+----------+------+
```

I tried both

```
and a.id > b.id
```

and

```
and a.id < b.id
```

both produced the same result above.

However, when I used

```
and a.id != b.id
```

It didn't work, instead it produced

```
+--------+--------+----------+------+
|     id |     id | building | room |
+========+========+==========+======+
| 413001 | 881256 |   Crosby |   10 |
| 881256 | 413001 |   Crosby |   10 |
| 496747 | 741532 |   Crosby |   19 |
| 741532 | 496747 |   Crosby |   19 |
| 612413 | 931027 |   Crosby |   31 |
| 931027 | 612413 |   Crosby |   31 |
| 170267 | 958827 | Dolliver |    1 |
| 958827 | 170267 | Dolliver |    1 |
| 104131 | 707536 | Dolliver |   14 |
| 707536 | 104131 | Dolliver |   14 |
| 477801 | 505241 | Dolliver |    8 |
| 505241 | 477801 | Dolliver |    8 |
| 118199 | 824292 | Kendrick |   1A |
| 824292 | 118199 | Kendrick |   1A |
| 105540 | 231742 | Kendrick |   3B |
| 231742 | 105540 | Kendrick |   3B |
+--------+--------+----------+------+
```

Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: I highly doubt that `a.id > b.id` and `a.id < b.id` produced the same results. If they did, wouldn't THAT be the concern? Your example output is very clearly the result of `a.id > b.id` so I suggest you run `a.id < b.id` version again and see that it produces different results. Your output for `!=` looks like the combination of those two, which is exactly what I would expect.

Comment: In SQL, the "not equals" operator is "<>", not "!=".  Have you tried "<>" ?

Comment: @MikeNakis [that's fine syntax for Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-comparison.html)

Comment: @JNevill oh, interesting.  Thanks.

Comment: The results you have are as expected, except that the first two results are not *exactly* the same. If you pay attention to the first two columns, you'll see that they are swapped when comparing the first two results. If you can confirm that is the case, you'll also better understand the third output.

Comment: What's the desired result? It seems to me the results you got are correct.

Comment: Yes, a.id > b.id and a.id<b.id product the same roommate pairs, @trincot yes, you are right, I did notice that the columns are swapped, but the roommate assignments are the same. What I don't understand is why != doesn't work, or according to Mike Nakis <> doesn't work either, as it produced the same result as !=. In my understanding, the logic of this query is to two unique individuals who share the same building and same room, so why != or <>, whichever, is not making the same result as < or >?

Comment: Just think of it, it works as expected. If you have 1, 2, 3 and required a.id < b.id, then you get (1, 2), (1, 3) and (2, 3). If you require a.id > b.id you get (2, 1), (3, 1) and (3, 2). And finally if you (only) require (the less restrictive) a.id != b.id then you get *all* of the above, ie. all possible pairs except (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3). What is your question really about this?

Comment: @trincot wonderful! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite normal. The results you have are as expected, except that the first two results are not *exactly* the same. If you pay attention to the first two columns, you'll see that they are swapped when comparing the first two results.

But the condition `a.id != b.id` is less restrictive than the other two and will therefore give more results.

#### For example:

If you have values 1, 2, and 3 and required `a.id < b.id`, then you get as possible combinations:

(1, 2), (1, 3) and (2, 3).

If you require `a.id > b.id` you get these combinations:

(2, 1), (3, 1) and (3, 2).

Note how these pairs are similar as above, but not the same: the order of the values in each pair is opposite -- corresponding to the condition.

And finally if you (only) require (the less restrictive) `a.id != b.id` then you get *all* of the above, i.e. all possible pairs except (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3):

(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1) and (3, 2)

In your query they are then ordered, but that does not change the essence: you get twice as many results with `a.id != b.id` than with one of the other conditions.